# Texmaths vs Texpoint?

Tags: presentations, powerpoint

I wonder if anyone has used both Texmaths for LibreOffice or Texpoint for Powerpoint. Is one significantly better than the other; does either have glaring limitations? I'm preparing some slides with lots of figures and equations so thought to use LibreOffice or Powerpoint instead of beamer, but wanted to get a sense of which equation editor is more developed.

Comment: How dare you dishonor the house of TeX with those filthy words...? just started this *game of thrones* thing sorry :)

Answer (score 3):

Both Texmaths and Texpoint plugins provide similar functionality (for LibreOffice and MS Powerpoint, respectively). However, it seems that Texpoint is no longer under active development, as the last updates (version 3.3.1) by the authors (Necula and Glatz) are from 2010, and their forums contain posts indicating that this version does not function with the current Office versions (2013). If you have an earlier version of Office (again, check the [forums](http://lists.texpoint.necula.org/pipermail/users-texpoint.necula.org/) for the last compatible version), Texpoint is great in Powerpoint (at least that was my experience). However if you are using current versions of Windows OS (at least 7) and Office (2013), exporting documents from LibreOffice+Texmaths to Word or Powerpoint at least provides a similar functionality, although the eqs themselves will appear only as images in MS Office, and thus cannot be edited as LaTeX objects directly; to do so would entail maintaining separate (Office and LibreOffice) versions of object files. Hope this helps --